# Magento custom controller action is called twice

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I added a ajax add to cart to the rwd theme, and the action controller is called twice for every http request. Any help with solving the problem or debugging is welcome, I already lost 2 weeks on this. This all works on our development environment, but acts weird on staging. The dev environment is hosted locally on MAMP, staging is hosted on OVH shared hosting.

edit2: removed irrelevant info

Comment: give me your site url

Answer (score 0):

found this error message in error.log
FastCGI: comm with server "/..../staging/index.php" aborted: error parsing headers: duplicate header 'Content-Type', referer: http://staging.xxxx.be/product.html

also found a solution here: http://blog.imseo.it/2014/09/08/magento-fastcgi-error-parsing-headers-duplicate-header/

The solution is to replace the function sendHeaders in
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php

```
public function sendHeaders()
{
    if (!$this->canSendHeaders()) {
        Mage::log('HEADERS ALREADY SENT: '.mageDebugBacktrace(true, true, true));
        return $this;
    }
    if (in_array(substr(php_sapi_name(), 0, 3), array('cgi', 'fpm')))
    {
        // remove duplicate headers
        $remove = array('status', 'content-type');

        // already sent headers
        $sent = array();
        foreach (headers_list() as $header)
        {
            // parse name
            if (!$pos = strpos($header, ':'))
                    continue;
            $sent[strtolower(substr($header, 0, $pos))] = true;
        }

        // raw headers
        $headersRaw = array();
        foreach ($this->_headersRaw as $i=>$header)
        {
            // parse name
            if (!$pos = strpos($header, ':'))
                    continue;
            $name = strtolower(substr($header, 0, $pos));

            if (in_array($name, $remove))
            {
                    // check sent headers
                    if ($sent[$name])
                    {
                        unset($this->_headersRaw[$i]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // check header
                    if (!is_null($existing = $headers[$name]))
                    {
                        $this->_headersRaw[$existing] = $header;
                        unset($this->_headersRaw[$i]);
                    }
                    else
                        $headersRaw[$name] = $i;
            }
        }

        // object headers
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($this->_headers as $i=>$header)
        {
            $name = strtolower($header['name']);
            if (in_array($name, $remove))
            {
                    // check sent headers
                    if ($sent[$name])
                    {
                        unset($this->_headers[$i]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // check header
                    if (!is_null($existing = $headers[$name]))
                    {
                        $this->_headers[$existing] = $header;
                        unset($this->_headers[$i]);
                    }
                    else
                        $headers[$name] = $i;

                    // check raw headers
                    if (!is_null($existing = $headersRaw[$name]))
                        unset($this->_headersRaw[$existing]);
            }
        }
    }

    parent::sendHeaders();
}
```